# Sum where at least N records equals x

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi is there a way to "find" if there are N values in a column by a ID field equals X amount?

Comment: please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: you will only get broad or "generic" answers if your question is not detailed enough to answer precisely

Comment: sorry thought the question was clear enough as it only has 2 columns and probably many ways to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 possible ways:

```
select *
from (
      select t.*
        , count(case when t.col='N' then 1 end) over(partition by t.id) as count_n
      from yourtable t
     ) d
where count_n >= 5
```

or a more traditional group by subquery

```
 select t.*, g.n
 from yourtable t
 inner join (
     select id, count(*) as n from yourtable y
     where y.col = 'N'
     group by id
     ) g on t.id = g.id
 where g.n >= 5
```

Another is to use "inner join lateral" like this

```
 select t.*, oa.n
 from yourtable t
 inner join lateral (
     select count(*) as n from yourtable y
     where y.id = t.id
     and y.col = 'N'
     ) oa on true
 where oa.n >= 5
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0b16c/3)